# search result error

Tags: php, mysql, search

This is my search query , if there is no result match , how can i display error ,
please help

```
 $sql="SELECT  * FROM course WHERE course_name LIKE '%" . $search_name .  "%'";
              //-run  the query against the mysql query function
              $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sql="SELECT  * FROM course WHERE course_name LIKE '%" . $search_name .  "%'";
              //-run  the query against the mysql query function
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1)
{
    echo 'There were no results.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)=="0")
{
echo "----------------"; //your code here
}
```